# Show title and description of youtube video link like facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, youtube

YouTube: get youtube title+ image+description like facebook

Right now i'm using

```
<?php

// Replace Youtube URLs with embed code
function embedYoutube($text)
{
$search = '%          # Match any youtube URL in the wild.
    (?:https?://)?    # Optional scheme. Either http or https
    (?:www\.)?        # Optional www subdomain
    (?:               # Group host alternatives
      youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com    # or youtube.com
      (?:             # Group path alternatives
        /embed/       # Either /embed/
      | /v/           # or /v/
      | /watch\?v=    # or /watch\?v=
      )               # End path alternatives.
    )                 # End host alternatives.
    ([\w\-]{10,12})   # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
    \b                # Anchor end to word boundary.
    %x';

$replace = '<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"</param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" width="425" height="344">
    </embed>
    </object>';

return preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
}

$string = 'Video1'.
'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLqAF9hrVbY'."\n".
'http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw';

echo embedYoutube($string);

?>
```

for embedding youtube videos but i want full description + title + link of the source for the video to be displayed along with it.
Does anyone have any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be a little pain in the ass, but you could use the Youtube feed api. This is a cutout from my own code:

```
$youtube = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$youtubeID.'?v=2');
$title ='<b>Youtube:</b> '. (string) $youtube->title;
```

Should do it. The loading is also pretty fast.

Comment: what about description or summary and thumbnail

Comment: Thumbs are available here: `$url = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtubeID.'/1.jpg';` Summary should be in the xml-file is you take a look. Please accept if the answer is correct.

Comment: thanks for the help but still i couldn't get the description out of it.

Comment: `$description = (string) $youtube->content;` but you might have to change `?v=2` to `?v=1` in the xml-loader

Answer (score 0):

Use CURL for example to get more information about youtube video from youtube API here is example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VS6J_XXVst0?v=2&alt=json&format=5
```

API http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api